Wet bulb globe temperature (HeatStress Package, Liljegren's method): Error with leap year
i'm trying to calculate the wet bulb globe temperature via the HeatStress package via Liljegren's method. I do have all needed input files (temperature, dewpoint, wind and radiation) with all the needed units in the .nc format - it also includes times and lat and lan for a raster over my project dimension. So far, so good - the reading in process also works fine, the extraction of the variables as well.
But when the code arrives at the calculation of the index itself, it calculates for a good minute and gives me the following error message:

Error in if (is.leapyear(year)) dpy = 366 else dpy = 365: Missing value where TRUE/FALSE is required

I did look into the extracted time values and all of the data looks fine how it is required by the manual.
I also tried integrating different leapyear functions as:
days_per_year <- function(year) {
if ((year %% 4 == 0 & year %% 100 != 0) | year %% 400 == 0) {
return(366)
else {
return(365)
  }
}

or
is.leapyear <- function(year) {
leap_year <- function(y) {
as.logical((y %% 4 == 0 & y %% 100 != 0) | y %% 400 == 0)
  }
if (anyNA(year)) {
return(rep(FALSE, length(year)))  # Behandeln Sie NA-Werte explizit
  }
sapply(year, leap_year)
}

or
is.leapyear <- function(year) {
if (is.na(year)) {
return(FALSE)  # Behandeln Sie NA-Werte explizit
  }
as.logical((year %% 4 == 0 & year %% 100 != 0) | year %% 400 == 0)
}

but it always resulted in the same error. Am I on the right track? Or is this additional function not even needed? How can I TRUE / FALSE this error message or is it somehow avoidable if I already have my time dates?
My code - without any leapyear add ons looks like this:
library(HeatStress)
library(ncdf4)
library(lubridate)

ncfile_t2m <- nc_open("t2m.nc") 
ncfile_d2m <- nc_open("d2m.nc")  
ncfile_wind <- nc_open("wind.nc")
ncfile_ssrd <- nc_open("ssrd.nc")  

tas <- ncvar_get(ncfile_t2m, "t2m")  
dewp <- ncvar_get(ncfile_d2m, "d2m")  
wind <- ncvar_get(ncfile_wind, "wind_speed")  
radiation <- ncvar_get(ncfile_ssrd, "ssrd") 

lon <- ncvar_get(ncfile_t2m, "longitude") 
lat <- ncvar_get(ncfile_t2m, "latitude") 
time <- ncvar_get(ncfile_t2m, "time")
origin <- ymd_hms("1900-01-01 00:00:00")  # Zeitursprung
time_posix <- origin + hours(time)  # Hinzufügen der Stunden zur Basiszeit


nc_close(ncfile_t2m)
nc_close(ncfile_d2m)
nc_close(ncfile_wind)
nc_close(ncfile_ssrd)


wbgt_result <- wbgt.Liljegren(tas = tas, dewp = dewp, wind = wind, radiation = radiation, 
dates = time_posix, lon = lon[1], lat = lat[1])

print(wbgt_result)

Thanks a lot!

You could check whether your time_posix deviates from the date format required by wbgt.Liljegren (yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS). This could be, e. g., a " UTC" suffix. Try to reformat your dates like so time_posix |> strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").

@I_O Thanks for the comment! This sadly didnt work. But now I managed to get rid of the leapyear error, but directly adressing the data from the input file by
wbgt_result6 <- wbgt.Liljegren(tas = ncfile$t2m, dewp = ncfile$d2m, wind = ncfile$wind_speed, radiation = ncfile$ssrd,                                 dates = time_posix, lon = lon, lat = lat)
The calculation went through, but the result data stayed empty: **> print(wbgt_result5)
$data
numeric(0)
$Tnwb
logical(0)
$Tg
logical(0)**

Could you share a peek into the data used by providing the output of c('tas', 'dewp', 'wind', 'radiation', 'time') |> Map(f = \(nm) get(nm)) |> list2DF() |> head(10) |> dput()?

This could very well be a calendar issue. If the calendar of your data is 360_day or all_leap / 366_day then the conversion to POSIXct will have an NA value for days that don't exist in the standard calendar, such as 2023-02-29. Thus the year value is NA and is.leapyear() will give you the error. Can you check and report the calendar of the data?
